# Wordpress elementor alignment issue

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, elementor, autoptimize

I used autompimize to optimize the site. Now I'm getting some alignment issues in the live site[live site alignment issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0MCt.jpg). On the Elementor edit panel, the alignments are perfect.[Elemtor edit panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym01h.png) How to fix this issue?